# ServiceController shows incorrect MachineName

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have the following Code

```
    private DataTable GetServices(string[] serviceNames)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Services");
        dt.Columns.Add("MachineName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ServiceName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ServiceStatus", typeof(string));

        ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
        foreach (ServiceController scTemp in services)
        {
            if (serviceNames.Contains(scTemp.DisplayName))
            {

                dt.Rows.Add(scTemp.MachineName, scTemp.DisplayName, scTemp.Status);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

It returns the following

> MachineName,ServiceName,ServiceStatus
>   .,Adobe Flash Player Update Service,Stopped
>   .,Application Experience,Running
>   .,Application Layer Gateway Service,Stopped
>   .,Application Host Helper Service,Running

`scTemp.MachineName` returns a `.`

How can i get it to return the real computer name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "." indicates the local computer. To use the real MachineName you can use the property [MachineName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename) of the class Environment.

To solve your problem you need to add a custom mapping if the MachineName of the ServiceController returns ".".

```
if (scTemp.MachineName.Equals(".")) {
  dt.Rows.Add(Environment.MachineName, scTemp.DisplayName, scTemp.Status);
}
else {
  dt.Rows.Add(scTemp.MachineName, scTemp.DisplayName, scTemp.Status);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN: ServiceController.MachineName - The name of the computer that is running the service associated with this ServiceController instance. The default is the local computer (".").

You can get local computer name via
Environment.MachineName

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename(v=vs.71).aspx